# While creating a docker-compose file, how is the image section written or what value goes for the image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Example:

```
version: ‘2’
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:8.0
```

I see two parts in the image value, Example: flask-redis:1.0 or mysql:8.0. This is understood that the second part is the Version. However, in one tutorial I just found the image section is written as
Image: tut:php_img

What does this indicate, because there is no mention of version.

Answer (score 1):

The second part (the one after `:`) is not version. While it can indicate a version, it is just a tag that can contain numbers as well as letters, in this case `php_img` (it just needs to comply with standard DNS naming rules).

So `mysql:8.0` is exactly the same as `tut:php_img`, where `tut` is equivalent to `mysql` and `php_img` is equivalent to `8.0` as long as you are working with them locally (there is a difference between them if you want to push them to a repository though).

Answer (score 1):

An image name is made up of slash-separated name components, optionally prefixed by a registry hostname.

A tag name must be valid ASCII and may contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods and dashes. A tag name may not start with a period or a dash and may contain a maximum of 128 characters.

So technically, if the two rules above are followed, the [IMAGE]:[TAG] is valid. Further on, it is just a matter of preference.

I believe the most popular convention is [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/). In some cases, semver is enhanced by adding other relevant metadata about architecture or the base-image used (`nginx:1.19.1-alpine-perl`).
Conversely, any convention can be ignored and the images can be tagged conveniently with the build-number or other identifiers that can be handy in a CI/CD pipeline for example.